# Formula to calculate salary based on different salaries and hours

Tags: ratio

My salary is 34,500 for 40 hours, what formula can I use to find out what is my salary for 39 hours then ?

I already tried this,

per week = 512.06 using website http://www.thesalarycalculator.co.uk/salary.php

then per day = 512.06 / 5 = 102.412

per hour = 102.412 / 8 = 12.8015

but how can I calculate it if my hours per week are 39 not 40

Comment: Differential equations?

Comment: only simple formula, no tag for it

Comment: Is it assumed that your salary varies directly with the time you work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You work 40 hours a week, and your salary is \$34,500 per year.  Assuming you work all 52 weeks in a year, you work $40 \times 52 = 2080$ hours per year.

Therefore, your hourly rate is: $\$34,\!500 / 2080 = \$16.59$ per hour.

So if you work 39 hours per week, 52 weeks a year, your salary will be $\$16.59 \times 39 \times 52 = \$33,\!667.50$

Comment: i think this is the answer, but why you used 52 weeks not 52.4

Comment: Where does 52.4 come from?